# Flatlist unique "key" pop warning

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

With my flatlist I get this message no matter what I try.

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

I don't have this issue when my data is a simple array.

```
const raceClass = <View style={[styles.countdownBoxes, styles.cdown]}>
    <Text style={[styles.titleText, styles.item]}>Race</Text>{timerComponents.length ? timerComponents : <Text>Time's up!</Text>}
</View>;
const deadlineClass = <View style={[styles.countdownBoxes, styles.dline]}>
    <Text style={[styles.titleText, styles.item]}>Deadline</Text>{timerComponentsDeadline.length ? timerComponentsDeadline : <Text>Time's up!</Text>}
</View>;

const flatListItems = [
    { title: "raceCountdown", text: "Race", content: raceClass, styleClasses: "styles.cdown" },
    { title: "deadlineCountdown", text: "Deadline", content: deadlineClass, styleClasses: "styles.dline" }
]
return (
    <View style={styles.timeContainer}>
        <FlatList
        data={flatListItems}
        numColumns={2}
        keyExtractor={(flatListItems) => {flatListItems.title}}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={styles.boxContainer}>
                {item.content}
            </View>
        )} />
    </View>
)
```

Comment: I have the same prop like this: `keyExtractor={(_, i) => i.toString()}` and it works fine for me.

Comment: You're right, looks like the stripped back simple example was somehow caching from a previous build. I have updated my question to just show my actual code instead of a stripped back example.

Comment: since the react is giving a warning means there must be duplicate keys or undefined. @NicolaeMaties your solution works but is not recommended as it destroys the idea of using key to remove unnecessary re-renders on array updates.
read more https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line:

`keyExtractor={(flatListItems) => {flatListItems.title}}`

Because you're using brackets around the function body, you must explicitly return the value. Your function is returning `undefined`.

With brackets:

`keyExtractor={(flatListItems) => {return flatListItems.title}}`

Without brackets also will work:

`keyExtractor={(flatListItems) => flatListItems.title}`

See the [MDN article on arrow functions here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#comparing_traditional_functions_to_arrow_functions).

This is assuming you can count on `title` to be unique in your `flatListItems`, as noted in the comment by Himanshu Patil.

Answer (score 0):

i get that warning fairly often when using flatlists. however, in most cases, it can be safely ignored and doesnt cause any trouble. the keyExtractor prop can actually be removed completely from the flatlist, and it still works fine. However, @Abe 's answer is perfect if you want to fix the problem, but the code runs even now